# taking values from future year to calculate current year value in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe which have 4-column like unique serial number ,year,calc1,calc2 where calc1 is the value from the future years for example at 2020 that value of calc1 is coming from 2023 and for 2021 value is coming from 2024 and so on till 2050.
Now I wanted to impute the values at year>2047 to be the value which is at 2050 that is (-0.00723716)

[image: This is what I wanted]

[image: This is the dataframe]

```
serial_number   calc1   cal2    year
26  -0.001501819    0   2020
26  -0.001985768    -0.000507896    2021
26  -0.00246321 -0.001008754    2022
26  -0.002588876    -0.001501819    2023
26  -0.00271944 -0.001985768    2024
26  -0.00284823 -0.00246321 2025
26  -0.002974961    -0.002588876    2026
26  -0.003097897    -0.00271944 2027
26  -0.003260818    -0.00284823 2028
26  -0.003422501    -0.002974961    2029
26  -0.003583018    -0.003097897    2030
26  -0.003742081    -0.003260818    2031
26  -0.003899622    -0.003422501    2032
26  -0.004098144    -0.003583018    2033
26  -0.004289239    -0.003742081    2034
26  -0.004486849    -0.003899622    2035
26  -0.004662517    -0.004098144    2036
26  -0.004833674    -0.004289239    2037
26  -0.005068817    -0.004486849    2038
26  -0.005300002    -0.004662517    2039
26  -0.005527554    -0.004833674    2040
26  -0.005752265    -0.005068817    2041
26  -0.005973502    -0.005300002    2042
26  -0.006233659    -0.005527554    2043
26  -0.006491639    -0.005752265    2044
26  -0.006744626    -0.005973502    2045
26  -0.006993511    -0.006233659    2046
26  -0.00723716 -0.006491639    2047
26  -0.00723716 -0.006744626    2048
26  -0.00723716 -0.006993511    2049
26  -0.00723716 -0.00723716 2050
```

Comment: Please, paste your table as text instead.

Comment: added the table data in text form